# Does crossref ever work?

Tags: bibtex

There's this seemingly useful field in bibtex that I vaguely remember having worked in the early 1990s, then not.  It's called crossref.

I get this error message: A bad cross reference---entry "Tomkins01" refers to entry "Campbell01", which doesn't exist

for this code:

```
@book{Campbell01,
  title={Sceptical essays on human rights},
  editor={Campbell, Tom and Ewing, Keith D and Tomkins, Adam},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},
  address = {Oxford},
  month=12
}

@inbook{Tomkins01,
  title={Introduction: On being sceptical about human rights},
  author={Tomkins, Adam},
  crossref = {Campbell01},
  pages={1--11},
  chapter = 1,
  annote = {}
}

@inbook{Bellamy01,
  title={Constitutive Citizenship versus Constitutional Rights: Republican Reflections on the {EU} Charter and the Human Rights Act},
  author={Tomkins, Adam},
  crossref = {Campbell01},
  pages={15--40},
  chapter = 2,
  annote = {}
}
```

I copied & pasted the crossref to make sure it was right! I'm using natbib in overleaf. Sorry if I'm being dense!

Comment: When using bibtex the crossref entries must come later, so you must move the Campbell01 entry behind the other entries.

Comment: This is compiling fine in Overleaf!

Comment: Ah, so the real error message should be "cross reference already defined so I can't use it, please move it later in the bibtex file?" @UlrikeFischer why don't you make that an answer instead of a comment and win your tick mark for your answer? It may not make sense, but it works!

Comment: @jak123 you mean my original code or Ulrike's suggestion? Yeah, I would give Ulrike the check if they'd made theirs an answer.

Comment: you can say "she" ;-).

Comment: Your code -- https://www.overleaf.com/read/hzbqvbtwrrrt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a restriction of bibtex: It doesn't look back, so a cross-referenced entry must come later in the database files than
every entry that cross-references it (and cross-referenced
entries cannot themselves cross-reference another entry).

So you must move the Campbell01 entry behind the other entries.

With biblatex + biber this wouldn't be necessary, there the order doesn't matter.